# How to copy records from sys.event_log in Azure SQL Database to a user-defined table in another database

Tags: azure-sql-database, deadlock, event-log

In our workplace, I do not have access to the master database.
I want to track "failed connections" and "deadlocks" So I decided to use `sys.event_log`.
How can I make a copy of the contents of this view to my database, and then monitor the Database status from there?
FYI: I suppose that I will take the access to make a copy of the data, somehow.

If there is another solution, without permission to master, please provide me.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We must need the [permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-event-log-azure-sql-database?view=azuresqldb-current#permissions) to query the `sys.event_log` table in master db :

**Users with permission to access the master database have read-only access to this view.**

The data in `sys.event_log` are dynamic growth. If we make a copy of the data, we still need access it first. Maybe you could ask Server admin to help you do that. Such as create extra source/table. Create a new table and copy data from the `sys.event_log` in the user database. Then you could access the copy table of the `sys.event_log`. The limit is that the data won't update in time.

I'm afraid we can not access the it without permission to master.

Comment: Thanks, Leon, as you mentioned, if I get access, then copy in another tebale might help.
But this view is created dynamically, then how you can call this procedure? What is the trigger? 
Is it possible to access the master from Azure Data Factory? For instance, create a procedure in the master that reads from this view and stores in user table. Then call this procedure from ADF. This is my idea.

Comment: With Data Factory, you also should make sure your AD account has the permission to access the master db. That's a good idea to create the create a procedure to get the data, then call the stored procedure in Source and output to Sink user database table(I would suggest using upsert in data flow). Schedule trigger the pipeline run according your request.  The premise is that  you may need the the people who have higher level permission to help you build the pipeline.